# Why does 3.times needs a .each if passed as an argument, but not when used directly, as in "3.times do xyz end"

Tags: ruby, enumeration, enumerable, enumerator

This is the simple version and works as expected

```
[15] pry(main)> def iter
[15] pry(main)*   3.times do
[15] pry(main)*     puts "Hello"
[15] pry(main)*   end  
[15] pry(main)* end  
=> nil
[16] pry(main)> iter
Hello
Hello
Hello
=> 3
```

But when I pass the Enumerator as an argument, it needs a `.each`:

Works:

```
[17] pry(main)> def iter(enumerator)
[17] pry(main)*   enumerator.each do        # <-------- Here  
[17] pry(main)*     puts "Hello"
[17] pry(main)*   end  
[17] pry(main)* end  
=> nil
[18] pry(main)> iter(3.times)
Hello
Hello
Hello
=> 3
```

Doesn't work:

```
[13] pry(main)> def iter(enumerator)
[13] pry(main)*   enumerator do         # <-------- Here
[13] pry(main)*     puts "Hello"
[13] pry(main)*   end  
[13] pry(main)* end  
=> nil
[14] pry(main)> iter(3.times)
NoMethodError: undefined method `enumerator' for main:Object
from (pry):8:in `iter'
```

I could be wrong, but it looks like Ruby is giving some special treatment to "3.times" a.k.a syntactic sugar. Is this the case, or am I wrong and the behaviour can be expected / deduced from first principles?

BTW, this works, too, which makes me suspect it's just syntactic sugar.

```
[19] pry(main)> def iter
[19] pry(main)*   3.times.each do
[19] pry(main)*     puts "Hello"
[19] pry(main)*   end  
[19] pry(main)* end  
=> nil
[20] pry(main)> iter
Hello
Hello
Hello
=> 3
[21] pry(main)>
```

Answer (score 3):

`3.times` is invoked and the result of that call (instead of a callable function) gets passed to `iter` function. And if `times` gets invoked without a block, it returns iterator. Iterator itself doesn't take a block, but you can invoke `each` on it.

Comment: Toms, it looks like 3.times returns an Enumerator:  
  

`[21] pry(main)> 3.times.class`
`=> Enumerator`
`[22] pry(main)> 3.times`
`=> #<Enumerator: ...>`

Comment: @vijucat, yes, but when you call `times` **with** a block, it doesn't return an enumerator, but rather invokes this block specified number of times. This behaviour is very common in ruby stdlib

Comment: The [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Integer.html#method-i-times) is quite clear: *"If no block is given, an Enumerator is returned instead."*

Answer (score 2):

Not syntactic sugar. Since Ruby 1.9 repetitive methods are built to behave like this:

- If there is a block, yield to it.
- If there is no block, return an Enumerator (by invoking something like `return to_enum(__method__) unless block_given?`)

Small example:

```
loop 
# => #<Enumerator: main:loop>
```